# How to find matching rows in Pandas DataFrame with identical values with same/opposite signs in certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, dataframe, matching

For the dataframe below, how can I return first and third row, as they have identical values in column "c" and "d", and have values opposite of each other in "a" and b"?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([ [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [-1,-2,3,4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
2 -1 -2  3  4
```

In other words, I want something similar to:

```
df1.duplicated(subset=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

The difference is instead of identical values in 'a' and 'b', the criteria is the values have opposite signs. And I want to return all matching rows.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry are you asking for any matches or rows that match the first row specifically? The following works specifically on matching first row: `In [11]:

df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.abs() == df1.iloc[0], axis=1).all(axis=1)]

Out[11]:

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
2 -1 -2  3  4`

Comment: Hi EdChum, thank you very much for the reply. No, I am not looking to match specifically the first row. Also it's not about matching absolute values, between 2 matching rows, values in column "a" and "b" must have opposite signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea should work:

1. Self join DF on c,d
2. Apply condition of opposite values...

A quick and dirty code

```
ndf = merge(left=df1,right=df1,on=('c','d'),how='inner')
out = ndf[(ndf.a_x == (-1)*ndf.a_y) & (ndf.b_x == (-1)*ndf.b_y)]
```

Please let me know if this works